# Origen de la expresión "de cabo a rabo"

Tags: modismos

Veo en el diccionario la expresión siguiente:

> **[de cabo a cabo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6S13ycd#4Yfxlin)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Del principio al fin.

Dado que *cabo* significa "el extremo de las cosas", la expresión parece clara: así, saberse algo *de cabo a cabo* significa sabérselo completamente (de principio a fin, *de pe a pa*).

Sin embargo, para mí la expresión ha sido siempre ***de cabo a rabo***. ¿Es esta expresión una simple deformación coloquial de la anterior? ¿O tiene un origen independiente que implique alguna acepción de "rabo"?

Comment: Ni idea pero  el DLE dice que *cabo*  viene de *caput* (cabeza), lo que daría bastante sentido a la frase de *cabo a rabo* que sería *de la cabeza al rabo.* Lo de *de cabo a cabo* no lo he oído ni leído jamás.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veamos cuándo comienza a usarse cada expresión.

*De cabo a cabo* aparece ya en documentos escritos a mediados del siglo XIII ([CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=5&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=301017%5C011%5CC000O30102017113003599.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20de%20cabo%20a%20cabo%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto5), [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=12&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=301017%5C011%5CC000O30102017113003599.1192.1188&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20de%20cabo%20a%20cabo%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto12)); *de cabo a rabo* se encuentra en un texto de 1553 ([CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=301017%5C011%5CC003O30102017113220067.1200.1196&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20de%20cabo%20a%20rabo%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0)) aunque luego no aparece más hasta 1772 ([CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=301017%5C011%5CC003O30102017113220067.1200.1196&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20de%20cabo%20a%20rabo%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1)).

Comparando con Google Ngrams (al cual no le faltará su sesgo, pero vale para esto):

[image: de cabo a cabo vs. de cabo a rabo]

No me explico ese pico de uso en torno a 1780. Fuera de eso, se ve con claridad que

1. *De cabo a cabo* parece ser la expresión original. El CORDE indexa desde mucho antes que Google, pero en ambas comparaciones el uso de *de cabo a cabo* precede por muchos años al de su alternativa.
2. Ambas expresiones estuvieron en uso juntas durante siglos; según Ngrams, convivieron por un siglo con la misma frecuencia aproximada (¡por lo menos en los libros!)
3. A partir de 1920 más o menos *de cabo a rabo* comienza a trepar en preferencia y su alternativa, que suponemos más castiza, pierde frecuencia, aunque no desaparece del todo.

No se me ocurre un ejemplo ahora, pero hay muchos casos de expresiones que se deforman, cambiándose una palabra por otra por mera similitud fonética. En este caso no sólo hay similitud fonética sino también semántica (el rabo es donde termina el cuerpo de un animal, es decir, uno de sus extremos, es decir, un "cabo") y además con *rabo* se mantiene la rima a la vez que se suprime cierta cacofonía.

Nótese que en el DLE se marca como "coloquial" la expresión *de cabo a rabo*. La expresión aparece por primera vez (según creo ver) en el Diccionario de 1869, y allí figura como "familiar". En ambos casos *de cabo a cabo* no está marcada especialmente con ningún registro.

[image]

Todo esto llevaría a suponer que *de cabo a rabo* es en efecto una innovación por deformación fonética sobre *de cabo a cabo*, que es expresión más antigua. No parece que haya significado nunca otra cosa.

Comment: La expresión *de cabo a rabo* existe antes del siglo XIX, la primera aparición en el CORDE data de 1553, aunque *de cabo a cabo* es claramente anterior ya que en el CORDE aparece en documentos sobre el año 1250.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección. No debí haber dejado pasar esa consulta. La he incorporado a la respuesta.